# Can I call [super didReceiveMemoryWarning] in viewDidDisappear?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, didreceivememorywarning

'Im using ARC and UINavigationController to switch between 10 viewcontrollers. Everything works great, but after a while `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called (because of all the open view controllers) and `[super didreceivememorywarning]` cleans out all the view controllers that aren't Super. That is perfect for me. The only problem is that when it is called the app lags for a second.

Can I call `[super didreceivememorywarning]` in every view controller's `viewDidDisappear`? 
That works perfectly when I test it, but is it allowed/stupid to do? If not, how can I release every view controller that isn't Super?

Comment: if didReceiveMemoryWarning is called, its never okay!

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the UIViewController documentation:

> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is called when the system determines that the amount of available memory is low.